# Один класс = 2-м контроллерам = Fail?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

Читаю в данный момент книги/статьи по поводу разработки приложений под iOS, везде не рекомендуется использовать один класс на 2 ViewController'a, ситуация следующая: У меня имеется один ViewController и ModalViewController, в модальном реализован ввод данных, которые отображаются в ViewController, собственно вопрос, почему не рекомендуется использовать один класс для 2 контроллеров?

[image]

Comment: Доброе время суток! А что мешает использовать два класса для двух контролеров?

Comment: Вероятно Вы хотели спросить, почему нельзя на два UIView повесить один UIViewController? Контроллер один, а вью - 2? Что такое "класс" в данном случае?

Comment: Добавил рисунок, он прояснит картину.

Comment: Странно, что Вы называете UIView классом. Нет, это класс, фактически, но и UIViewController тоже класс. Короче говоря, Вам нужно почитать о MVC (Model-View-Controller design pattern). Когда Вы поймете какие задачи возложены на каждый компонент, Вы сможете ответить на свой вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю по тому, что это неудобно. Т.е. вы хотите подгружать разные UIViewController для одного класса? Проще создать отдельный класс для отдельного вида, и переходить на него можно как на модальный.

```
для подгрузки:
[mainViewController presentModalViewController:myModalViewController animated:YES];

для возврата:
[myModalViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Можно подгружать из кода разные состояния по условию, т.е. при проверке условия вы выбираете какие именно контролы показывать и где их располагать. Еще можно, опять же по условию(например юзер не залогинен), сначала показывать один UIViewController , а при выполнении условия(например все поля заполнены и мы залогинили юзера) загружать основной UIViewController.

Все-таки удобней будет иметь для каждого контроллера свой класс, чтобы не было сильной нагруженности на один класс.
Если вы хотите использовать данные введенные в какой-то форме, то лучше создайте класс для данных и при их введении сохраняйте их, а потом считывайте из этого класса там где вам нужно.

Comment: У меня такая ситуация, есть один класс, в нём обьявлен TextField, а как мне в другом классе взять этот TextField и вынять с него значение?

Comment: вот написал вам пример с вариантом класса ДанныхЮзера http://my-files.ru/9mkv.1111.zip
надеюсь поможет )
P.S. c обменником этим работаю первый раз, если не скачается - пишите. )

Comment: @tragvar, спасибо большое за пример, а можете дать пример с комментариями и на сторибордах?
Я не совсем понял, точнее не понял как всё работает..